# Responsive Menu hides inside the ads

Tags: css, menu, responsive-design

my responsive menu is in side the adsense code here is the css of menu. I have an responsive website www.idealbanker.in but while clicking menu it goes in side the adsense ads kindly guide me to resolve it.

my responsive menu is in side the adsense code here is the css of menu. I have an responsive website www.idealbanker.in but while clicking menu it goes in side the adsense ads kindly guide me to resolve it.my responsive menu is in side the adsense code here is the css of menu. I have an responsive website www.idealbanker.in but while clicking menu it goes in side the adsense ads kindly guide me to resolve it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYW6z.png)

```
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.topnav li {float: left;}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #555;}

/* Hide the list item that contains the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}
@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens */
@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}


</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
</script>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
ul.topnav.responsive {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Add `z-index` property to specify the stack order.